# Datepicker Computes Age

Tags: jquery, datepicker

**I have a code which computes age but it seems wrong because the base I think 1950.**

Now I want to compute the age in  **Current time**  and selected date on datepicker.

Example: the date now is **11/24/14**  and if i pick on datepicker is **11/24/13** the output is *1*. PLEASE HELP ME.

HTML

```
<div class="checked" id="age"></div>
<input id="dob" />
```

JQUERY

```
  $('#dob').datepicker({
  onSelect: function(value, ui) {
    console.log(ui.selectedYear)
    var today = new Date(), 
        dob = new Date(value), 
        age = ui.selectedYear - 1950;

    $('#age').text(age);
},
maxDate: '+0d',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
defaultDate: '-18yr',
});
```

here is the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/441/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate age, you need to get the current year using `getFullYear()`:

```
age = today.getFullYear() - ui.selectedYear;
```

***Snippet***:

```js
$('#dob').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(value, ui) {
        var today = new Date(), 
            age = today.getFullYear() - ui.selectedYear;
        $('#age').text(age);
    },
    maxDate: '+0d',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    defaultDate: '-18yr',
});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="dob" />
<div class="checked" id="age"></div>
```

Comment: thank you very much sir abhitalks. It works. can ask question? how can i disable the year based on current time. Example: now is 2014 subtract to 18 years. so the past years will be disable. 1997 - current date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract the current year from the selected date.

```
$('#dob').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(value, ui) {
        var today = new Date().getTime(), 
            dob = new Date(value).getTime();
            age = today - dob;
            yoa = Math.floor(age / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25); // age / ms / sec / min / hour / days in a year
        if(yoa < 18){
            under18();
        }else{
            overOrEqual18();
        }
    },
    maxDate: '+0d',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    defaultDate: '-18yr',
});

function overOrEqual18(){
    $('#age').text('you are old enough');
}
function under18(){
    $('#age').text('you are NOT old enough');
}
```

I suggest that you convert their selected date to a timestamp so that you can more accurately calculate their age rather than just using the year they have selected (this will mean that it accommodates for the day/month as well as the year).

I have added functions that will allow you to perform things based on whether the input is over or under 18 years of age.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/444/)**

EDIT:
As per your comment on another answer. If you change `maxDate: '+0d'` to `maxDate: '-18yr'` this will disable selection of dates less than 18 years before today

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/445/)**

Comment: @kentyo you're very welcome, please dont forget to mark an answer as correct if the solution helped. This way visitors to this question will be able to find what worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function comp(){
       var bday=document.getElementById('bday').value;

        var today = new Date();
        var birthDate = new Date(bday);
        var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
        var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();

        if (today.getMonth() < birthDate.getMonth() || (today.getMonth() == birthDate.getMonth() && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
            age--;

        }

        document.getElementById('age').value=age;
    }
```

Comment: Please add some description to your code. It helps people to understand what you added